# Main thread does not continue execution after pthread_create()

Tags: c, pthreads

I've created a thread using `pthread_create()`. The new thread is created successfully and the control passes to the newly created thread. However, it seems like the main thread does not execute anymore. The main thread is in an infinite loop and never exits. Following is a snippet of the code:

```
void *start_routine(void)
{
    printf("Start routine reached!\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    printf("Pthread returning!\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    return NULL;
}

void create_thread()
{
        pthread_t newThread;

        printf("Thread create reached!!\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        /* Create the new thread */
        if((pthread_create(&newThread, NULL, start_routine , NULL)) != 0 ){
                perror("pthread_create");
                fflush(stdout);
        }

        printf("Thread create done!!\n");
        fflush(stdout);

        return;
}
```

The output is:

```
Thread create reached!!
Start routine reached!
Pthread returning!
```

I don't see "Thread create done!!" being printed and the program is just stuck at this point.

Any pointers would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Can we see the main thread code that spawns the new thread?

Comment: Does it help if you change the signature of start_thread so that it accepts a `void*` argument?

Comment: You'r start_routine's signature is incorrect. It should be `void *start_routine(void* arg)`. In addition, it is a good practice to call `pthread_join()` from the main thread to wait for the spawned thread to finish execution.

Comment: Renaming your `void create_thread()` to `int main()` and running it, causes corrupted output (duplicated lines). Adding a `pthread_join()` fixes that.

Comment: Is printf thread safe?

Comment: I changed the signature of the start_rotuine and added pthread_join() as well in the main thread. But, I still see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It should be caused by your wrong signature of `start_routine`. the standard signature of entry routine for `pthread_create` is `void *(*start_routine)(void *)`. In implementation of `pthread_create`, provided `start_routine` will be called, with the argument for `start_routine`, in your case, `create_thread` provides it with value `NULL`, thus, in `pthread_create`, `NULL` is pushed into stack before calling `start_routine`, However, your `start_routine` does not restore the stack as `pthread_create`(exactly an internal routine called by `pthread_create`) expecting, after `start_routine` finished, the stack is out of expect, and likely run into address `NULL`, this may cause your program abort soon.

The problem occurs when the argument is transferred via stacks. To correct it, just correct your `start_routine` to be `void *start_routine(void* args)`. And, in the main thread, calling `pthread_join` to waiting for the spawned threads to be finished, otherwise, resource leaking will be a potential problem.

If you interest in internal working of Linux NPTL `pthread_create`, you may visit http://raison.gegahost.net/?p=91 .

Comment: I changed the signature of the function to void *start_routine(void* args) but I still see the same issue. I'm not sure if it has something to do wit the environment I'm running it in.

Comment: @RSM it is `void * start_routine(void * args)`, not `void start_routine(void args)`.